# no response from jquery .on('hide', function

Tags: jquery, hide, show-hide

I have some divs that I show/hide.  I want to reset the forms inside these divs every time they are hidden, but this does not seem to work:

```
$('#div_id_1,#div_id_2').on('hide',function(){
    $('#form_id_1,#form_id_2').each(function(){
        this.reset();
    });
});
```

This function never gets triggered.  How to I capture this "hide" event?

Thanks

Comment: the event hide is a custom event??

Comment: When are you hiding these events? I'm not sure if I get you, but couldn't you just use the callback in `.hide()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to either put your reset code in the place where you actually do the hiding, or simply trigger a 'hide' event yourself:

```
$('#somelink').click( function() {
  $('#div_id_1').hide().trigger('hide');
} );
```

This is because there is no `hide` event triggered by jQuery itself (see [docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)).

Comment: Yes i suspected this, I will just have to add `.trigger('hide')` to my hiding functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need trigger the `hide` event manually.

```
$('#div_id_1').hide('fast', function() {
   $(this).trigger('hide');
});
```